# How to read and print information from a file using def?

Tags: python, function

I need a program that would read information from a .txt file, which contains a person's name and his/her age. The trick is that ***there can be any amount of names and ages***, but they also can ***repeat but count as one person***.

So the .txt file can be random but follow the platform of Name1 Age1:

```
Sarah 18
Joshua 17
Michael 38
Tom 18
Sarah 18
Michael 38
```

Python has to be told to print out the youngest and oldest person into a **new .txt** file?

I'm guessing the printing in the new file should look like:

```
Joshua 17
Michael 38
```

But I really do not know how to even start.

I hope I'm right when I start coding like this:

```
info = open("info.txt", "r")

list = info.read()
print (list)

info.close()
```

But I don't know how to determine the oldest and youngest with def.
Any tips or suggestions that could set me on the right track?

Comment: By "with def", do you mean using a function?

Comment: You need to read the file line-by-line. You need to split each line into a name/age pair. You need to keep track of the youngest person seen so far and the oldest as you read each line. At the end, you need to output the youngest and old persons to a new file. Which part do you need help with?

Answer (score 3):

Using Dictionary will be Good here:

```
my_dict = {}
with open('your_file') as f:
    for x in f:
        name, age = x.strip().split()
        my_dict[name] = age
print max(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
print min(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. I suggest the following code, but I'll let the writing-to-file part to you:

```
def parse_info(): #If you need, the function can be wrapped up in a function like this. 
    #Notice that you can edit and pass info via arguments, like filename for example
    info = open("info.txt", "r")
    max_age = 0
    max_name = ''
    min_age = float('inf') #sentinel just for the comparison
    min_name = ''

    for line in info:
        m_list = line.split(" ") #Represents 'Sarah 18' as ['Sarah', '18'] 
        if int(m_list[1]) > max_age: #Compares if you have found an age higher than any other already found
            max_age = int(m_list[1])
            max_name = m_list[0]
        elif int(m_list[1]) < min_age: #Compares if you have found an age lower than any other already found
            min_age = int(m_list[1])
            min_name = m_list[0]

    print ('Max age: ', max_name, ' ', max_age)
    print ('Min age: ', min_name, ' ', min_age)

    info.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("sort_text.txt")
columnAge = []
for line in file:
    columnAge.append(line.split(" ")[1].strip() + " " + line.split(" ")[0].strip())
columnAge.sort()
print(columnAge[0].split(" ")[1] + " " + columnAge[0].split(" ")[0])
columnAge.sort(reverse=True)
print(columnAge[0].split(" ")[1] + " " + columnAge[0].split(" ")[0])
file.close()
```

Output:

```
Joshua 17
Michael 38
```

---

References:

[list_sort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_sort.htm)
[string_split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)